# TryParseExact doesn't receive valid format c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to input a datetime value from the console. However, The TryParseExact method doesn't receive valid formats:

```
string startdate;
DateTime inputDate;
while (true)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Input time [HH:MM TT]");
   startdate = Console.ReadLine();
   if (DateTime.TryParseExact(startdate, "hh:mm tt",
                              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                              DateTimeStyles.None, out inputDate))
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of `startdate` exactly? And `while(true)` ?

Comment: Works for me. What are you entering that seemingly doesn't work?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What kind of values can they have? startdate is input from the console. example: 12:00 PM

Comment: @user3541104 show an example of the kind of input you are using?

Comment: @user3541104: You are saying that it isn't accepting input that you think is valid. I have tested it and it accepted the valid input that I gave it so you should tell us what you inputted that didn't work. You should also tell us what your CurrentCulture is in case that is relevant.

Comment: Also confirm with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx that your format actually says what you think it does. eg you are mandating that you need leading zeros. Also the `:` in the format doesn't necessarily mean a literal colon but the time separator for the culture being used (so might be a `.` for some cultures).

Comment: @user3541104: i think you are entering hours in 24- hour format, if yes then try to use capital `HH`

Comment: @user3541104 also, are you including the space before the AM/PM in your input; if you can specify what you're inputting we can check.  What code's outside of your loop - i.e. could you be exiting the loop without realising it, perhaps because there's another loop around that?

Comment: Well I guess the problem was with the cultures after all. My misunderstanding came because I don't quite understand the cultures. After I changed it to InvariantCulture, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not accepting input that you think is valid then there are two possible causes of the problem:

1) The input is not what you think it is. This could be caused by copying and pasting from somewhere else that is including non-valid characters or something. IF you are manually typing the number then this is unlikely to be an issue.

2) The format you are accepting is not what you think it is. This is most likely since there are some subtleties that can bite you on this. The key think is to look up everything in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and be aware that several elements you are using are culture dependant. You are obviously at least partially aware of cultures since you are explicitly stating you want the current culture. Without knowing what that culture is though its hard to say what the input should be.

A case in point is that in your format `:` doesn't mean a literal colon but the "Time Separator". To quote the MSDN page: "The ":" custom format specifier represents the time separator, which is used to differentiate hours, minutes, and seconds. The appropriate localized time separator is retrieved from the DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator property of the current or specified culture."

As you can see this means that it is not always `:`.

Often the best fix, especially since you are hard definining the format, is to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which will guarantee not to change depending on where you run the software, etc. Otherwise you should generate the string that specifies the correct input using the relevant components of your current culture object.

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to write this without the `white(true)` loop / to try to make it easier for your users:

```
string startdate;
DateTime inputDate;
while (inputDate == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input time [HH:MM TT]");
    startdate = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact
    (
        startdate, "hh:mm tt"
        ,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        ,DateTimeStyles.None
        , out inputDate
    ))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("'{0}' is an invalid value."));
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
        Console.WriteLine(
            String.Format("Example: The time now is '{0}'"
            ,DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
        );
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("That's a valid time :)");
```

NB: your above code works in so much as given the correct input (for your user's current culture) the code exits the loop.

Comment: How does this make it easier for users out of interest?